# WP send email- change notification to new email

Tags: wordpress

I try to find a way to send the notification email, in Wordress, after changing the email of a user to his new email and not to the old email he had before.

I found a way to do that in the wp-includes/user.php file. But every time wp is updated, the changes are overwritten. What can I do to fix this?